Masstransit's inbox configuration
I'm publishing messages from the asp.net controller using outbox. On the receiver side, i expect them first to be saved into the InboxState table(to avoid duplicates) and after that handled by the consumer-side worker to the consumers. But messages somehow are handled to the consumers directly, without saving them into inbox table.
My consumer is like that:
public class OrderWithEmailConsumer
    : IConsumer<SendEmailWithOrderDetails>
{
    private AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private ILogger<OrderWithEmailConsumer> _logger;

    public OrderWithEmailConsumer(AppDbContext dbContext, ILogger<OrderWithEmailConsumer> logger)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SendEmailWithOrderDetails> context)
    {
        // send email to the customer
        _logger.LogInformation("Sending email to {Email} with order details", context.Message.Email);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _dbContext.Emails.Add(new OrderSentEmail()
        {
            EmailAdress = context.Message.Email,
            Subject = "Order details",
            Body = context.Message.OrderDetails
        });

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        _logger.LogInformation("Email sent to {Email}", context.Message.Email);
    }
}

and i configure outbox model like this(on the consumer's side)
configurator.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<AppDbContext>(c =>
{
    c.QueryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    c.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    c.DuplicateDetectionWindow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    c.DisableInboxCleanupService();
    c.UsePostgres();
});

configurator.AddConsumer<OrderWithEmailConsumer>();

And the DbContext class
public class AppDbContext: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<OrderSentEmail> Emails { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.AddInboxStateEntity();
        modelBuilder.AddOutboxMessageEntity();
        modelBuilder.AddOutboxStateEntity();
    }
}

What i tried, is to look into InboxState table after publishing message, but it gives me 0 rows. I also tried to log all the db operations that it makes, but apart from polling outbox table i see no polling inbox? i really don't understand how can i configure inbox table polling

You can also reproduce the error i face by docker-compose-up'ing this repo
https://github.com/usersuseruuseruser/MtSample. Just publish the message using "order-send-with-email" endpoint and check the Inbox table, for example by psql means

You need to actually configure the outbox on the consumer's endpoint. You can do this in the Consumer Definition or via a configure endpoints callback.
These options are covered in the documentation.
